# linq to sql loading children on one to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables. Incidents, Rootcauses, and IncidentRootCauses. The table incidentrootcauses is tied to Incidents as a one to many. When I get the Incident object, There is not a list of rootcause objects as a I expected, instead I am getting (In my Immediate window)

```
var rt = incident.IncidentRootCauses;
```

{System.Data.Linq.EntitySet}
    Count: 1

```
HasLoadedOrAssignedValues: true

IsDeferred: false
```

I would like to be able to load all of the rootcause objects when the query runs. I know the problem is that incident is not tied to the rootcause table explicitly. Thank you for any help with this.

```
using (var db = new IncidentTrackerDataContext())
            {
                var lo = new DataLoadOptions();
                lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.ReportedTo);
                lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.Shift);
                lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.Machine);
                lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.Department);
                lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.IncidentRootCauses);
                lo.LoadWith<IncidentRootCause>(i => i.RootCause);

                // lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.IncidentManagers);
                // lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.IncidentMembers);
                // lo.LoadWith<Incident>(incidents => incidents.IncidentWitnesses);
                db.LoadOptions = lo;
                db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
                Incident incident = (from i in db.Incidents
                                     where i.IncidentReportID == new Guid(incidentID)
                                     select i).FirstOrDefault();

                return incident;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you also want a second level of eager loaded entities.

On the same LoadOptions, try:

```
lo.LoadWith<IncidentRootCause>(irc => irc.RootCause);
```

Comment: I have now added that to the list I am now getting an error message "Message":"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type \u0027IncidentTracker.Incident\u0027."

Comment: @user516883 it seems like `RootCause` also has a reference back to Incident. Also, make sure you don't `LoadsWith<IncidentRootCause>(irc => irc.Incident)` Can you post your table DDL for the 3 tables please?

Comment: The serializing exception is not related to the loadoptions (that would say "Cycles not allowed") but to json/xml serialization (I assume) that occurs afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the generated SQL. When trying to load multiple children, some of the load with options may be ignored because it would potentially mean pulling too many records. As a result, some of your child records may not be pulled until after the using clause has already been exited.